# Undefined symbol: EVP_BytesToKey installing mod_qos

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm attempting to install mod_qos and I'm getting the following error when attempting to start Apache:

```
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 203 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_qos.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_qos.so: undefined symbol: EVP_BytesToKey

Line: 203: LoadModule qos_module modules/mod_qos.so
```

OS

```
[root@server]# uname -a
Linux net-kyani-n13 3.4.43-43.43.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon May 6 18:04:41 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Researching this issue I found a similar error here: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3431267&group_id=196697&atid=958491

We do, however use mod_ssl so that module is already installed and compiled.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you compile this module yourself or is it just a binary?

Comment: Compiled using the `apxs -i -c  mod_qos.c ` command

Comment: This "could" be related to SSL libraries - seems odd it compiles fine if you're getting that error. I believe the package is `ssl-dev` or `libssl-dev`. It varies.

Comment: As hinted in the previous comments, this might be a version mismatch. Check that the module is for the exact version of apache you are running, and that the other modules in use also agree.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that mod_ssl is loaded **before** mod_evp in your config file.